# ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired, exception is java.sql.SQLException

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbctemplate, alter, autocommit

```
jdbcTemplate.execute("alter table UKIADATA rename to UKIADATA_temp");

jdbcTemplate.execute("alter table UKIADATA_2 rename to UKIADATA");

jdbcTemplate.execute("alter table UKIADATA_temp rename to UKIADATA_2");

logger.info("Tables swapped.");
```

I am getting error SQL [alter table UKIADATA rename to UKIADATA_temp]; ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired,

In addition to this can you help me how can I insert commit statements in this piece of code .

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the table you are trying to rename is occupied by another session (reading, inserting data, updating, deleting). In order for your request to run without this error, you must close other sessions or stop accessing this table.
DDL operations do not require fixing, they require fixing only the insert, update, delete commands. 
Any DDL command will also commit the data before starting its work.
This SQL will determine which sessions are blocking the table.
And the following SQL will forcefully terminate these sessions.

```
select s.sid, s.serial#
from v$locked_object l, dba_objects o, v$session s
where  o.object_name in('UKIADATA','UKIADATA_2')  and 
l.object_id = o.object_id and l.session_id = s.sid 

alter system kill session 'sid,serial#'
```

Comment: What is the solution , how can i close session in code before altering database table